# Google app engine - Submiting a Form

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I have created this servlet method:

```
/**
 * Create the entity and persist it.
 */
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Creating User!!!");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    try {
        user.insert(email, password);
        Log.info("Inserted: " + email + "    " + password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = DAOUser.getErrorMessage(e);
        out.print(msg);
    }
}
```

and want to insert into the GAE DB through this from, values:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/user" method="put">
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <div class="control-group">

                                                <!-- Text input-->
                                                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email:</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input name="email" placeholder="email" class="input-xlarge" type="text">
                                                    <%=request.getParameter("email") %>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="control-group">

                                                <!-- Text input-->
                                                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password:</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input name="password" placeholder="password" class="input-xlarge"
                                                        type="text">
                                                    <%=request.getParameter("email") %>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
<div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> <a
                                        href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Save
                                        Changes</a>
                                </div>
```

However, it does not work, event the servlet is mapped correctly:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DAOServletUser</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

What is my mistake?

**UPDATE**
when I restart the server I get this:

```
Mär 22, 2013 6:46:07 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class gaeTrader2.server.dao.DAOServletUser is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:243)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:228)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$Servers.startup(DevAppServerImpl.java:451)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:198)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Why?

**Servlet class gaeTrader2.server.dao.DAOServletUser is not a javax.servlet.Servlet**

My Servlet looks like that:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.mortbay.log.Log;


public class DAOServletUser extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DAOServletUser.class.getCanonicalName());
    /**
     * Get the entities in JSON format.
     */

    IDAOUser user;

    /**
     * Create the entity and persist it.
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Creating User!!!");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        try {
            user.insert(email, password);
            Log.info("Inserted: " + email + "    " + password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = DAOUser.getErrorMessage(e);
            out.print(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: I get no error message at all... Therefore the configuration of the application must be wrong. However, I do not really see the mistake, pls help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using doGet or doPost on the server and a correspondig method in the client side.

UPD:
Your servlet description in the web.xml doesn't seem complete either:

`<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DAOServletUser</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>your.package.name.YourServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DAOServletUser</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: btw I changed the `method="post">` in the html tag and also the servlet method to from the name `doPut` to the name `doPost`. However I get nothing(also no request in firebug...)

Comment: @maximus Are you sure the form submits at all? Are you sure the servlet is accessible at all? Can you verify both of those things?

Comment: You are definitely right. I am sure that the servlet should be accessible ,because I used the same configurations for the servlet in my `web.xml` as you posted above. On the other side, when I press the `Submit Changes` Button I do  not really get a response, and also firebug shows no `POST` Request.

Comment: You need an <input type="submit" /> **INSIDE** your <form> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your DAOServletUser class should extend from HttpServlet.

Comment: and you're using doPost instead of doPut?

Comment: The gaeTrader2.server.dao.DAOServletUser is not a javax.servlet.Servlet one? And you're using the javex.servlet.HttpServlet import?

Comment: The DAOServletUser is my servlet. However, when I import in eclipse the classes that I need I get: `import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.mortbay.log.Log;` Are these classes wrong?

Comment: The imports are correct. Btw, where in your form is the submit button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26702/discussion-between-maximus-and-stijn-haus)